# GridView behaves differently on Emulator and release apk

Tags: android, gridview, apk, emulation

I have a Gridview, which works fine on the Emulator, but when I generate signed apk (release apk), the height of one element inside the gridview is different compared to the others. I don't know, what I'm doing wrong.

In my GridView I have an order like this:

### A B C D

### E F G H

### I J K D

Strangely, the element  "D" is also shown as a last element, but there should be the element "L" 
On Emulator "L" is shown, but not when I generate an apk. Here is the xml file:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/android_coordinator_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_android_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="@dimen/expanded_toolbar_title_margin_start"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/logonew"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"
           />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/nestedscrollview"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/grid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:columnWidth="100dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:listSelector="#00000000"

            />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, the device widths of your emulator phone and the one on which you install the release apk are different. Since you fixed the columnWidth to 100dp, the phone with the larger width can accommodate the views, while the other one can not. Make an emulator of the same device on which you install the release apk, and see if this happens then too. You can also try to play with different columnWidths. Try reducing it to say 80dp or 50dp, and see what happens then.
If the problem persists, please attach the screenshots of both the devices.